# HTML tags are not rendered while iterating over an array in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am quite new to ReactJS and still playing with the basic concepts, so the answer to my question might look obvious for pros ;)

**I have a component as below:**

```
import React from "react";

function NameList(props) {
  const names = ["Bruce", "Clark", "Diana"];
  return (
    <div>
      {names.map((x) => {
        <h1>{x}</h1>;
        console.log({ x });
      })}
    </div>
  );
}

export default NameList;
```

Can someone tell me why the h1 tags are not rendered while the values are written in the console?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add `return` before the `<h1>` tag based on the syntax which have been used:

```
function NameList(props) {
  const names = ["Bruce", "Clark", "Diana"];
  return (
    <div>
      {names.map((x) => {
        console.log({ x });
        return <h1>{x}</h1>;
      })}
    </div>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit relaxed-feather-frdd9]

Answer (score 2):

**You will need to return something from a `map()` function:**

```
import React from "react";

function NameList(props) {
  const names = ["Bruce", "Clark", "Diana"];
  return (
    <div>
      {names.map((x) => {
        console.log(x);
        return <h1>{x}</h1>;
      })}
    </div>
  );
}

export default NameList;
```

**Or direct return like this:**

```
import React from "react";

function NameList(props) {
  const names = ["Bruce", "Clark", "Diana"];
  return (
    <div>
      {names.map((x) => (
        <h1>{x}</h1>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}

export default NameList;
```